# What is the technical and semantic differences between the following prototype inheritances

Tags: javascript

I recognize this is a duplicate question. I'm trying to get a very narrow and specific answer.

When working with JavaScript prototype inheritance patterns I came across two popular ones.

#### Given

```
function Animal(type) {
  this.type = type;
}
Animal.prototype.makeNoise = function(noise) {
  console.log('the ' + this.type + ' goes ' + noise);
}
```

Style and best practises aside, what is the technical and semantic differences between these two object definitions:

```
function Dog() {
  Animal.call(this, 'dog');
}
Dog.prototype = new Animal();

function Cat() {
  Animal.call(this, 'cat');
}
Cat.prototype = Animal.prototype;
```

They appear to both do the same thing as demonstrated in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qaseg/2/edit). Best I can tell is that Cat gains the inheritance without the extra instantiation that Dog's definition executes. Could use some insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second version, the prototypes of `Cat` and `Animal` are *shared*, meaning that when `Cat.prototype` is changed, `Animal.prototype` (and all its inheritors) will be affected as well.

Check out this example:

```
Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
  console.log("Woof!");
};

Cat.prototype.meow = function() {
  console.log("Meow!");
};

'bark' in Animal.prototype; // => false
'bark' in Cat.prototype;    // => false
'meow' in Animal.prototype; // => true - Oops!
'meow' in Dog.prototype;    // => true - Oops!
```

So, now, our dogs (and all the other potential animals) know how to meow.

I'd say, then, that the first strategy is generally safer, as it makes each type owner of their prototype.

---

On a side note, I'd suggest using [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) instead of the constructor when creating the prototype for `Dog`/`Cat`:

```
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

This avoids any unwanted logic that the `Animal` constructor might have, while retaining the same advantages. You can also define additional properties on the [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) call directly - check out the documentation I linked to.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was hoping for. Thank you.  Also note that the MDN docs suggest setting the constructor property.